# signed exe coming up with publisher unknown with makecert

Tags: makecert, signtool

I am attempting, for internal use at the moment, setup a self installing exe which is signed and comes up with our company as the publisher and not "Unknown".  I have executed the following steps:

***makecert.exe -sv Our.pfk -n "CN=Our Company" Our.cer***

I entered the desired password, first for the certificate and then for the pfk file.  Then I combined the pfk and cer files into a pfx:

***pvk2pfx.exe -pvk Our.pfk -po  -spc Our.cer -pfx Our.pfx -po "password"***

finally I run signtool:

***signtool sign /f Our.pfx /n "Our Company" /d "Our Install" /p "password" "exename"***

However, when attempting to run the install the publisher comes up "Unknown". Am I missing a step?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the certificate was not issued by a trusted root authority. I tried to run these commands on Windows 8/VS 2012 and got the error "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority." on the last step.